# Proper TERM type for eshell

Tags: eshell, term

Is there a way to make eshell behave better? By default `printenv TERM` returns `dumb`. For example `brew` often complains about the terminal type and causes eshell to "jiggle" while the progress bar is showing.

This doesn't happen in `term`. I suspect this is because `TERM=eterm-color`.

I know I could just add `brew` to `eshell-visual-commands`, but are there any ways of making `eterm-color` work in eshell.

Here's the video of `brew` behaving weirdly. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the error mentioned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFhM_ToLuaQ

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? `eshell` sets `TERM` to be `dumb` for a reason--it can't handle a lot of fancier command line interaction (à la `top` and `ssh`). `brew` works fine for me through `eshell`, and even outputs colors and emoji.

Comment: @shosti Updated the question with a video example

Comment: The visual glitches are due to problems with eshell's rendering, not related to the `TERM` variable (if anything, setting `TERM` to be something different would make these kind of problems worse since programs will output more control sequences that eshell can't handle). Unfortunately, I think the answer is "live with it or try to fix eshell".

Comment: @shosti What should I do with this question now? Close it? You answer it? I answer it?

Comment: Up to you--you might want to reword it and see if anyone has a real answer (I'd be interested if someone did)

Comment: From the video it seems to me, Emacs's (rather stupid) auto scroll feature is making the buffer dance. I guess you should try setting `auto-window-scroll` to `nil` and `scroll-conversely` to large number (>100)

Comment: @kindahero that would be `scroll-conservatively`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @shosti pointed out, `eshell` simply doesn't support any fancy escape sequences.

However my problems with `brew` can be fixed by resetting `fringe-mode` and disabling `truncate-lines` in `eshell` buffer.

This ensures characters don't wrap to the next line and that long lines (such as the progress bar) don't get covered by the `truncation` glyph.

I've tried @kindahero suggestions about the scroll, but to no avail.